# how can I create several databases and some schemas as a SQL statement, with postgres

Tags: postgresql

how can I achieve this:

```
CREATE DATABASE test0;
CREATE SCHEMA s0; <- in test0

CREATE DATABASE test1;
CREATE SCHEMA  s1; <- in test1
```

without using pgsql, so no /connect in between.

do I have to log as admin, create the dbs, then connect under each db and then create the schemas? or can I do all at once when logged as admin?

Comment: You need to be connected to the database in which you want to create the schema.

Comment: so if I log as admin, I can connect to any db to create the new databases, but when I want to create the schema, I have to connect directly to the right db, correct? how does it work with init.sql when you initialize the db the first time? does that mean it's not possible to create schemas there?

Comment: Right. Creating a database does not require that you are connected to that database (of course). But creating an object **inside** the database requires you to be connected to that database.